# unable to fix the issue when used bootstrap classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I see two issues with my code. Header is not getting fixed and second issue is word wrap is not applicable for the headers/rows.
I have used bootstrap classes, but still facing issues. I want to fix the table header and only rows should be scrollable and if the text is long it should automatically word wrap. I have multiple columns in my application(approximately 15 columns).Please advice.

To view the sample code [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1415/).

Sample html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                <table id="myTable" class="table table-fixedheader table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>

                        <tr class="row">
                            <th class="col-md-3">Header1</th>
                            <th class="col-md-4">Header2Header2Header2Header2</th>
                            <th class="col-md-3">Header3</th>
                            <th class="col-md-4">Header4</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">5443545435354543</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">5437665</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">5435435443</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">68678454</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">786876</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">8787876</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">6765767</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">7656765</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">656456</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">116611</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">43434</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">43243432434324342</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33344343233</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">4343</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">432434343243243</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">432443</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">333333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">111312312123121</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">32112</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Its your content. word wrapping only breaks at spaces. your first 11111.... is just one long string with no spaces so it displays on one line. I think a modal is not the best option for displaying your table data. Alternatively increase the size of the modal so that it fits most of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a non table approach. If your ok with having set widths on the columns with content wrapping in the cells. Here's an example https://codepen.io/flurrd/pen/jmMNxK?editors=1100

Note: Class names are terrible in this example. I'd BEM it up for proper usage.

```
.table-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.t-row {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
.t-row:nth-child(even){
  background: #e3e3e3;
}
.col {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  max-width: 33.3333%;
}
.cell {
  padding: 8px;
}


<div class="table-wrap">
  <div class="t-row t-header">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell">
        Header 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell">
        Header 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell">
        Header 1
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="table-body">
    <div class="t-row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="cell">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="cell">
          1111
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="cell">
          11111111
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```